# serializing parent/child relationships with newtonsoft.json and linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, json.net

I am having a problem.  I have a table tblitems which has a primary key which has a child table tblweeks linked via foreign key.  When using json.net to serialize json, even when the reference loop handling is set to referenceloophandling.ignore, it is serlilizing the parent tblitem class for every tblweekof linked to it.  I don't want that but I still want some fields from the child class.  Is there a way in my linq query to only select some columns from a child table or do I have to break the relationships?  I'm confused, this seems like really unexpected behavior.

**UPDATE**

OK, I kind of have what I want now, I found I could use the select function on the child table to only select certain columns, but what is the best way to garentee the order of the child records?  I want to make sure they are ordered by weekof in this example:

```
var q = from lineITem in db.tblBroadcastEntryItems 
        where lineITem.broadcastID == Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString[0])
        select new 
        { 
            ..., 
            week = lineITem.tblBroadcastEntryWeeks
                           .Select(c => new { c.weekof, c.spots, c.id })
        };
```

Comment: Post your code, your data, the output you are getting now, and the output you are trying to get instead.

Comment: OK, I kind of have what I want now, but I want to do an order by on the child table to order it by weekof in ascending order.  Here is the linq query that I have so far.  Where can I put the order by so that within the week collection it is always ordered by weekof var q = from lineITem in db.tblBroadcastEntryItems where lineITem.broadcastID == Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString[0]) select new { ..., week = lineITem.tblBroadcastEntryWeeks.Select(c => new { c.weekof, c.spots, c.id })};